# Mandrill Adding a Space to a URL

Tags: mandrill, transactional-email

Using [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) I'm sending an email that has a link:

```
<a href="http://www.slotted.co/NzIyNnx0c2NvdHRAc2xvdHRlZC5jbw==">
  http://www.slotted.co/NzIyNnx0c2NvdHRAc2xvdHRlZC5jbw==
</a>
```

As expected Mandrill replaces my HREF with a tracking link:

```
http://mandrillapp.com/track/click/30319089/www.slotted.co?p=eyJzIjoiT1h4VE04RlV2bWp5R2YzNjZkNnNWaFpOemJ3IiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMDMxOTA4OSxcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwOlxcXC9cXFwvd3d3LnNsb3R0ZWQuY29cXFwvTnpJeU5ueDBjMiBOdmRIUkFjMnh2ZEhSbFpDNWpidz09XCIsXCJpZFwiOlwiM2NmMWE4MzUzNGE1NDg4ZTg1OTUwMDkxZmFhY2M5NTNcIixcInVybF9pZHNcIjpbXCI3YWM1ODFiMTJkY2E0YWM4YzZlMmM3ZDU2OWU2YzQ5MmMxNDIxMDJmXCJdfSJ9
```

This link redirects to:

```
http://www.slotted.co/NzIyNnx0c2%20NvdHRAc2xvdHRlZC5jbw==
```

Notice the extra `%20` in the middle of the path which obviously breaks the link. [You can try it yourself](http://mandrillapp.com/track/click/30319089/www.slotted.co?p=eyJzIjoiT1h4VE04RlV2bWp5R2YzNjZkNnNWaFpOemJ3IiwidiI6MSwicCI6IntcInVcIjozMDMxOTA4OSxcInZcIjoxLFwidXJsXCI6XCJodHRwOlxcXC9cXFwvd3d3LnNsb3R0ZWQuY29cXFwvTnpJeU5ueDBjMiBOdmRIUkFjMnh2ZEhSbFpDNWpidz09XCIsXCJpZFwiOlwiM2NmMWE4MzUzNGE1NDg4ZTg1OTUwMDkxZmFhY2M5NTNcIixcInVybF9pZHNcIjpbXCI3YWM1ODFiMTJkY2E0YWM4YzZlMmM3ZDU2OWU2YzQ5MmMxNDIxMDJmXCJdfSJ9).

Seems like a bug, but I'm still on the free plan, so no way to report it. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you disable tracking, do you still have the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28763812/90287):

> We typically see this kind of issue with SMTP libraries or frameworks
>   that generate HTML with no true line breaks. The SMTP specs state that
>   the line length for email shouldn't exceed 1000 characters. When that
>   limit is reached, a line break gets inserted automatically when the
>   message data is being transmitted over SMTP. This unfortunately often
>   happens right in the middle of a word or a URL, for example. You'll
>   want to take a look at your SMTP library to see if you can modify how
>   line breaks are being handled.
>
> If you're using HTML line breaks like `<br>` that are being used to
>   indicate a break, those unfortunately won't help in this case. Adding
>   your own line breaks (not HTML line breaks, but actual line breaks in
>   the data such as a newline or end of line - usually `\r\n` - will help
>   ensure that the forced line breaks aren't arbitrarily added in the
>   SMTP conversation in inconvenient places.